# Keras does not recognize tensorflow install in miniconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am using miniconda and Jupyter notebooks. The environment my notebook is using has python 3.7.9, tensorflow 2.3, numpy 1.18.5, and keras 2.4.3

when I first ran from my notebook:

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

I got an error that `C:\Users\Tristan Kosciuch\miniconda3\envs\tf\Lib\site-packages\~umpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` had permission denied.

I managed to install tensorflow into the environment using `pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow`, but now when I `import keras` I get `ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher.`!

`!jupyter-troubleshoot` shows I have tensorflow 2.3.0 in my pip list...

The full error from `import keras`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      2 try:
----> 3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomRotation' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' (C:\Users\Tristan Kosciuch\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\layers\experimental\preprocessing\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

~\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

Comment: have you shut down all kernel when you tried to install tf?

Comment: Keras now comes with Tensorflow > 2.0. Have you tried to `import tensorflow.keras` ?

Comment: Now when I do import tensorflow, I get error 
  File "C:\Users\Tristan Kosciuch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: @ manuel that was a good suggestion, if I get around the import tensorflow error and keras still doesn't work I'll try your suggestion. @ Micheal I believe I did, I shut down my notebooks, opened a new env and ran pip install tensorflow (and my other packages) from the miniconda command prompt. Still didn't get it working. I'll revisit it this week and post any progress I make. Thanks!